# How do I put a text (value) inside an input type="text" using php

Tags: javascript, php, input

I'm trying to make the input write out "Hello", but it simply stays blank. What am I missing? It might be a duplicate, but I cannot find an answer. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
include ('dbconnection.php');
$username="Hello";

if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
echo "<script> document.getElementById('usernamelogin').value = '$username';
    </script>";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button">Test</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Fred -ii- Sorry, I updated it. This was just a little sample I put together, the id is there now. my bad! But even with the id on the input it still won't work.

Comment: Your JavaScript is executing before the element exists on the page.  So `getElementById()` isn't going to find that element at that time.

Comment: Do you want to use JS or PHP?

Comment: *Would you like white or rye Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1st way (your way but fixed):
Your need to put your php under the HTML so that when the JS code executes the HTML elements are all created, so that the JS can select them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>



<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button">Test</button>
</form>
<?php 
include ('dbconnection.php');
$username="Hello";

if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
echo "<script> document.getElementById('usernamelogin').value = '$username';
    </script>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

2nd way (IMO better):
Is this solution I insert the value directly with php, so no JS is required

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>


<?php 
include ('dbconnection.php');
$username="Hello";

?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button">Test</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For other reasons I need the js there, but moving the php was all I needed. Probably huge roomie mistake, but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: It will work but it is not the cleanest way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an ID of input not name.

```
<input id="usernamelogin" type="text" name="usernamelogin">
```

Comment: ahem... the guy changed it and that's not my dv there

Answer (score 0):

Why hassle! by using JS

simply use

```
<input type="text" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
```

Comment: True but what if they want to use JS? Isn't that what the OP wants to achieve here?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you are right with that concern, but don't you think, it is irrelevant doing it through JS, because i can see the blueprint of the document here, where this could not be needed.. :) isn't it!

Comment: Blueprint? There is no blueprint here, only a question.

Comment: Yup, I don't think OP has added full script here, he has just added an mark-up of his requirement, that's what I called it as blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that javascript thingy. Go straight to php, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
include ('dbconnection.php');
$username="Hello";

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="usernamelogin" name="usernamelogin" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"><br>
    <button type="submit" id="button" name="button">Test</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if they want the, um, *"javascript thingy"*?